How to build gpio-pca953x.ko with kernel 6.1?
I'm trying to build gpio-pca953x.ko module for latest Debian. Few days ago I've build this module with linux-image-6.1.0-24, but after upgrade to 6.1.0-25 build fails:
tar xf linux-source-6.1.tar.xz 
cd linux-source-6.1
cp /lib/modules/6.1.0-25-rt-amd64/build/.config .
cp /lib/modules/6.1.0-25-rt-amd64/build/Module.symvers .
make menuconfig
make scripts prepare modules_prepare
make M=drivers/gpio

  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-mmio.o
  LD [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-generic.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-amd-fch.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-amdpt.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-exar.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-f7188x.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-kempld.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-ml-ioh.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-pca953x.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-pcie-idio-24.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-pci-idio-16.o
  CC [M]  drivers/gpio/gpio-viperboard.o
  MODPOST drivers/gpio/Module.symvers
ERROR: modpost: "__mutex_init" [drivers/gpio/gpio-pca953x.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "_raw_spin_unlock" [drivers/gpio/gpio-pcie-idio-24.ko] undefined!
ERROR: modpost: "_raw_spin_unlock" [drivers/gpio/gpio-pci-idio-16.ko] undefined!
make[1]: *** [scripts/Makefile.modpost:127: drivers/gpio/Module.symvers] Error 1
make: *** [Makefile:1986: modpost] Error 2

What is wrong ?

Have you tried to simply diff -urN src24/ src25/ and  see what have been changed?
